# How to restore less recent Whatsapp backup from iCloud drive?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

My Whatsapp iCloud backup didn't restore any chat history. I did backup about 100mb file to ICloud drive. However, when I tried to restore the backup, It was just one chat message and not the full chat history. I logged in to iCloud drive to find any backup files. But I don't see any backup files there either. Is there anyway to access my missing backup file or restore it?. I use iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 1):

Do you backup WhatsApp messages in WhatsApp settings or iPhone Settings? If so, you cannot access or view the backup files in iCloud Drive because it is not saved in iCloud Drive. It is unreachable like your iPhone backup.
As for the situation that you just got one chat history back, I think it is a bug. You can reinstall WhatsApp and try again.